# why mouse select in linux ssh will trigger ctrl+C automatically?

Tags: linux

I use putty/mremote to connect a linux, but when I try to select some text use mouse, it always send a ctrl+C automatically, which will send a interrupt to linux and will break my operation.

I test it and find that is only happened on my windows machine.
how to solve this?
Thanks.

Comment: It is probably a client configuration issue in PuTTY. A question like this is probably more appropriately asked over at http://superuser.com

Comment: It's mostly caused by applications with text highlight detection like translators which allow you to instantly translate highlighted texts. I've had similar problems with **QTranslate** while it's mouse mode was activated.

Comment: @zxcmehran haha I was looking for a solution and it turned out that I had installed QTranslate. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

On my computer, the mRemoteNG has the similiar issue. Whenever I use mouse to select text, a ctrl+c is sent to server automatically.

I find it's caused by one translation software YoDaoDict(Chinese name: 有道翻译). You can stop it（关掉有道翻译（词霸之类的在线翻译软件）） or turn off the function of translate on selection (或者关掉划词翻译（选词翻译）之类的功能).

Answer (score 1):

Certain translation software such as "词霸秒译" and "金山词霸2016" support "select and automatically translate". If you enable those features, it can cause this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, turning off automatic translation software seems to fix this, particularly when using x-term from cygwin or any other non-Windows terminal on a Windows machine that has software installed which intercepts the action of mouse selection or terminal movement on Windows. It does not matter whether you have an SSH session on a Linux box. This happens because of very basic selection interception. Windows movement selects the whole windows and causes the same.